# How to display a different images on a SecondViewController when a button is pressed on the MainView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, xcode6, ios8.3

I have two ViewControllers. My first view has two buttons (button1 & button2, each button segues to a second view with a `UIImageView`.

What I want to happen is when I press button1 an image is to be displayed in the second view and when I go back to my first view and press button2 a different image to appear in the view. I have been able to achieve this with using a tableView but thats not really the way I want to lay out my design.

Comment: Both buttons segue to the same view controller, and the only difference between the buttons is which image gets shown in the second view controller, correct?

Comment: Yes that is right. Unfortunately i can not add images yet as i am new around here it wont let me :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any view controller implements `prepareForSegue`, you can override this function to pass data to the destination view of your segue.

1. Assign to your two segue an identifier in your storyboard, let's say *button1* and *button2*
2. In the first view controller override `prepareForSegue`

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
       let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
       if segue.identifier == "button1" {
           destination.image = image1
       } else if segue.identifier == "button2" {
           destination.image = image2
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the second view controller, inside `viewDidLoad` you can set the image of your UIImageView based on the `image` property you set on point 2.

   ```
   class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
       var image: UIImage!
       @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

       override viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           imageView.image = image
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:** remember to change the name of your second view controller to yours.
I've assumed you have two properties in your first view controller that contains the two images, but you can also load them in `prepareForSegue` or just pass images name and load the image in the second view controller.

Comment: Hi i have added the code as above to my FirstViewController. In my SecondViewController i have added                                                            var image:UIImage? = nil                                                                                then in the viewDidLoad                                                               imageView.image = image  I get an error in the prepareForSegue with the lines destination.image = image1 and destination.image = image2 The Error is: Use of unresolved identifier 'image1' & the same error for image2. Sorry i couldn't upload images

Comment: As I've said I've supposed your FirstViewController has two properties (image1 and image2) of type UIImage that contains the images. If you don't want to add this properties you can also create the necessary image inside prepareForSegue.

Comment: how do i create the necessary images inside prepareForSegue

Comment: You can use UIImage(named: "image.png"). If you use an asset the name of the image is not the name of the file with the extension but the name of the image set.

Comment: ah yes this is what i have done but get the error "Can not assign a value of type 'UIImage?' to a value of type UIImageView.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to set the image in the imageView. I've only necessary code supposing you have connected your imageView to the outlet

Comment: I had added that code to my SecondView. I have added a link to Onedrive with sceen shots of code as i cannot add images on here yet [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CB8562788C7A548B!169&authkey=!AF-JKSnPtMJ0J9Y&ithint=folder%2cpng)

Comment: Replace _Car1_ with a newly created UIImage as said in previous comment

Comment: Worked, seems so simple now. Really appreciate the help :-)